# ¿Cómo hago un SELECT con (AND) y (OR) en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

¿Cómo puedo realizar correctamente la siguiente consulta?

```
SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE id = `1` AND categoria = `php` OR categoria = `js`
```

Quiero que se seleccionen:

- todos los registros cuya ID sea igual a 1,
- y cuya categoría sea "php" o "js".

Comment: ¿Donde quieres realizar la consulta? Porque la consulta esta bien construida. Deberías cambiar esas comillas `` por las comillas simples normales ' '.
SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE id = '1' AND (categoria = 'php' OR categoria = 'js'); También fijate en que tipo de dato es id, numérico o texto.

Comment: A la consulta le falta el paréntesis para que funcione correctamente. De la forma que la tienes construída, el sistema la entiende como que **se seleccionen los registros cuya ID sea "1" `Y` tengan categoría "php" `O` que tengan categoría "js" sea cual sea su ID**. La forma correcta sería poner un paréntesis después del AND y hasta el final. ```SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE id = '1' AND (categoria = 'php' OR categoria = 'js')```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La forma correcta de hacerlo sería utilizando un paréntesis después del `AND`, es decir:

```
SELECT * FROM nom_tabla WHERE id = '1' AND (categoria = 'php' OR categoria = 'js');
```

Es importante tener cuidado con las comillas, en este caso con comillas simples `''`.